# How to adjust a SharePoint form with SharePoint designer without stopping the synchronisation?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form, list-form, newform

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 to change the 'New Item' form for my list.

I don't have so much experience with coding, but I was able to change some small things (like deleting some columns and adding a few blank lines and so on..).

My problem is that for example if I change the column ordering (in SharePoint in the List Settings) the form looks exactly like before (does not change with my new settings).
That means that the form always stays the same even if I change things which is not that great.

Is it possible to adjust the form via coda a little bit but without loosing the 'synchronization'? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you want to change order of column on the lists forms?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've changed a form using SharePoint Designer it won't be based on the site definition anymore, so most of the changes will have to be done by hand from that point.
That, of course doesn't mean you cannot use some interesting functionallity like: [Customize Data Views and forms](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-Data-Views-and-forms-using-SharePoint-Designer-4201233c-ce24-42c2-9f2a-31f202c440cc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

The link is for SharePoint 2010, but I found it very useful and most of the details work in SharePoint 2013 too.

Comment: Thank you!
I read the article but it doesn't really help me with me problem. In SharePoint 2013 it is only possible to change the forms via code. Could you explain to me which aspect you think could help me with my problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need your forms to have any special behavior, maybe you can reset your forms to the Site Definition again, and then every change you do OOB (i.e. using list configuration) will be reflected again. Don't forget you can use infopath to customize your forms too, but I encourage you to avoid infopath, because it will be lack of support in future versions.

Comment: But I do need some special behavior. So I guess a middle course is not possible? :(( Something like 'do not change this section' but 'from here on synchronize please'

Comment: can you detail a bit more about your "special behavior" ?

Comment: I want to change the first five columns (add comments, layout, delete some columns,..) and I don't want to change the rest of the columns. That means for example if I add a new column I want it to appear in my new item form. But with the custom form I would have to write the new column in the code by myself (its not happening automatically). It would be awesome If there was a command that says 'do not change this section, it should stay like this even if something in sharepoint changes' and another command that says 'please synchronize with sharepoint': Hope you see what I mean!

Answer (score -1):

Hope you have some issues with SharePoint form synchronisation after updations. You can try recreating the form again and try. Or if you love coding you can try [HillyBillyForms](http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/) for customising SP forms without designer.

Comment: But if I create it again I would have to do it every single time I change something. This doesn't sound good to me! :( 
Actually I am not that good at coding. Is there another option?